# How do I measure cache performance in multithreaded applications?

Tags: linux, caching, profiling

I need something like cache hits/misses on a per thread basis. How do I obtain that information? Cachegrind doesn't seem to work, based on the fact that my sequential program gives a count of X instructions executed, and of Y for my parallel program, all OK, except for the fact that X=Y.

I assume Cachegrind is not for threads? Any other tools I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use perf to get the information you want from the hardware performance counters.

try:

```
$ perf stat -e cache-misses,cache-references /bin/ls /tmp/
...

Performance counter stats for '/bin/ls /tmp/':

             3,534 cache-misses              #   16.605 % of all cache refs    
            21,283 cache-references                                            

       0.001649284 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: But `perf stat` can't  output separated per-thread counters; only summary... http://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat "By default, perf stat counts for all threads of the process and subsequent child processes and threads. This can be altered using the -i option. It is not possible to obtain a count breakdown per-thread or per-process."